# How to set border color on individual items on click by map functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, material-ui

I have an array which is consisted with some data. My Array is,

```
const faqData = [
    {
      q: "How Can We Help You?",
      a: "Below are answers to our most commonly asked questions. If you cannot find an answer here, please contact us.",
    },
    {
      q: "How Can We Help You?",
      a: "Below are answers to our most commonly asked questions. If you cannot find an answer here, please contact us.",
    },
    {
      q: "How Can We Help You?",
      a: "Below are answers to our most commonly asked questions. If you cannot find an answer here, please contact us.",
    },
  ];
```

For showing all of the data of the array inside cards, i am using map function which is,

```
 {faqData.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <SimpleFlexContainer
              sx={{ flexDirection: "column", m: "20px 0px" }}
            >
              <SimpleFlexContainer
                sx={{
                  background: "#F4F4F5",
                  width: "100%",
                  p: "15px 25px",
                  justifyContent: "space-between",
                  alignItems: "center",
                }}
              >
                <SimpleFlexContainer>
                  <SmallTypo
                    sx={{ fontWeight: "bold", mr: { xs: "15px", md: "25px" } }}
                  >
                    Question
                  </SmallTypo>
                  <SmallTypo sx={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{item.q}</SmallTypo>
                </SimpleFlexContainer>
                <Box>
                  <IconButton>
                    {openDes ? (
                      <RemoveIcon onClick={() => setDes(false)} />
                    ) : (
                      <AddIcon onClick={() => setDes(true)} />
                    )}
                  </IconButton>
                </Box>
              </SimpleFlexContainer>
              <Box
                sx={{
                  display: openDes ? "inherit" : "none",
                  background: "white",
                  p: "26px",
                  border: "1px solid #F4F4F5",
                }}
              >
                <SmallTypo>{item.a}</SmallTypo>
              </Box>
            </SimpleFlexContainer>
          );
        })}
```

When users click on the individual cards, i want to show a border color around that specific card. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use state to hold the clicked item's index

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState('')
```

then, you can have a style in one of the outer `SimpleFlexContainer` like

```
sx={{borderColor: clicked === index ? 'your_favourite_color': ''}}
```

and don't forget to remove the index value when clicked outside or leave it if you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks. It was an easy solution. I made it so complex.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this is to create a separate component. Something like this:

```
import { useState } from 'React';

const FAQComponent = (props) => {
 const {
  item,
 } = props;
 
 const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
 const [openDes, setDes] = useState(false);

 return (
           <SimpleFlexContainer
              sx={{ flexDirection: "column", m: "20px 0px" }}
              onClick={() => setActive(pre => !pre)}
            >
              <SimpleFlexContainer
                sx={{
                  background: "#F4F4F5",
                  width: "100%",
                  p: "15px 25px",
                  justifyContent: "space-between",
                  alignItems: "center",
                }}
              >
                <SimpleFlexContainer>
                  <SmallTypo
                    sx={{ fontWeight: "bold", mr: { xs: "15px", md: "25px" } }}
                  >
                    Question
                  </SmallTypo>
                  <SmallTypo sx={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{item.q}</SmallTypo>
                </SimpleFlexContainer>
                <Box>
                  <IconButton>
                    {openDes ? (
                      <RemoveIcon onClick={() => setDes(false)} />
                    ) : (
                      <AddIcon onClick={() => setDes(true)} />
                    )}
                  </IconButton>
                </Box>
              </SimpleFlexContainer>
              <Box
                sx={{
                  display: openDes ? "inherit" : "none",
                  background: "white",
                  p: "26px",
                  border: "1px solid #F4F4F5",
                }}
              >
                <SmallTypo>{item.a}</SmallTypo>
              </Box>
            </SimpleFlexContainer>
 )
}
```

Now you can map out your component somewhere else:

```
 {faqData.map((item, index) => <FAQComponent key={item.a} item={item} />)}
```

**NOTE**: It's very important for React to put `key` argument on mapped components, you can use any other field from item object that's unique.

And after this, use `active` constant to determine whether you should change the border or not.

Comment: Good Answer. Worked for me too.